# Populating only ONE column on MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, triggers

I need to build a MySQL table. 
I have tables: weapons, armor, trash.
They all have primary keys: `idweapon, idarmor, idtrash`.

I need to build a table that holds every item, so the table should look like:

```
iddatabase (pk) 
idweapon(fk)
idarmor(fk)
idtrash(fk)
```

How can I tell the database that only ONE of the three later columns can be populated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using integers for each of your keys (they are all the same type), try a schema like this instead:

```
iddatabase(pk)
iditem
itemtype
```

Comment: Yes, all are integer because they're referring to ids from other tables.
But, help me understand this, please.
I'll have id from every other table here, so there'll be many 'iditem' with the value= '1'.

For example:
0,0,armor
0,1,armor
0,0,weapon
0,0,trash

This won't have any problem?

Comment: Rather than a separte column for each item type, you have one column that can hold the foreign key from any of your tables, with an additional column telling you which table it belongs to.

Comment: I'll try doing a script to fill this. Thanks for the suggestion. This was the first idea I had, but my teacher told me to scratch it for some reason. I'll do it anyways and explain to her how this'll work.

Comment: If you're in a class, do what the teacher suggests. They may have learning goals that put artificial constraints on a problem.

Comment: Not a goal, she was giving me her opinion on how to make it easier.
ALSO: How would I go about making this a foreign key? Or should I just leave it as an integer without relation to the other tables?

Comment: SQL Server has support for conditional indexes you could use. I don't think MySql will let you index this properly. MySql isn't really a modern DB anymore; it hasn't kept pace with other options over the last decade+, missing features like APPLY, CTEs, windowing functions, and much more.

Answer (score 1):

"How can I tell the database that only ONE of the three later columns can be populated?" to me reads that you only want one of three columns to be able to hold a value and the other two must be NULL.

If so, a trigger can achieve this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger
BEFORE INSERT ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    IF  NOT((NEW.idweapon IS NOT NULL AND NEW.idarmor IS NULL AND NEW.idtrash IS NULL) OR
           (NEW.idarmor IS NOT NULL AND NEW.idweapon IS NULL AND NEW.idtrash IS NULL) OR
           (NEW.idtrash IS NOT NULL AND NEW.idweapon IS NULL AND NEW.idarmor IS NULL)) THEN
               SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'   
               SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Only one column should have a value';
    END IF;

END;
```